# Is this the right way to Select distinct from table with mySql?

Tags: mysql, select

I want to sum the "grundfrakt" where the userId is distinct from my image. So I want to sum only one value per userId and ordernummer.

I get the value 115, and it is correct with this select query.
And I just want to be Absolutely sure that I´m doing it the right way?
So I don´t miss anything that can mess it up!?

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT grundfrakt) FROM cart where ordernummer='176748409';
```

[image]

Thanks!

---

New question!

Thanks The Impaler, it works great. But how can you do the same if the "grundfrakt" is in an other table(users)? Thanks again.

So I have the "cart" and the "users" tables, and I want to get the distinct "grundfrakt" from the users table instead.

[image] [image]

Comment: What happens if a `userId` has multiple different values for `grundfrakt`?

Comment: No, you aren't summing a single value per user id, just discarding identical values. Apart from the syntax, how can MySQL know you want to take userid into account? It isn't even in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `grundfrakt` always has the exact same value for the `userid`/`ordernummer` combination, the query you need is:

```
select
  sum(x.m)
from (
  select max(grundfrakt) as m
  from cart
  where ordernummer = '176748409'
  group by userid
) x
```

To answer the second question, you can just do a simple `JOIN`, as in:

```
select
  sum(x.m)
from (
  select max(u.grundfrakt) as m 
  from cart c
  join users u on u.userId = c.userId
  where c.ordernummer = '176748409'
  group by u.userid
) x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot The Impaler, just what I needed :-). However can you help me to produce the same, but when I have the "grundfrakt" in another table? I will update my question with the new senario.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson Answered the second question now.

Comment: Thank you very much The Impaler. I will test it in the morning, big thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help The Impaler, it works great!